# How to get the data from <script> with no attributes inside <body>?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract all coordinates of locations of the restaurant using beautiful soup.How can i extract all of them from the script tag under the body?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import urllib2
import json

base_url = 'https://locations.wafflehouse.com/'
r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
print all_scripts[19]
```

Comment: What do you mean by: with no attributes? Edit your post with the desired output please

Comment: @newcoder i have updated my answer, please check!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER:
You need to parse the json in `json.loads()` and then navigate, try this code...working smoothly!

```
import json, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
req = requests.get('https://locations.wafflehouse.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all('script')[19].text.encode('utf-8')
jdata = data.replace('window.__SLS_REDUX_STATE__ =', '').replace(';', '')
data = json.loads(jdata)
for i in data['dataLocations']['collection']['features']:
    LatLong = (i['geometry']['coordinates'])
    print(LatLong)
```

Output:

```
[-90.073113, 30.37019]
[-84.131085, 33.952944]
[-78.719497, 36.14261]
[-95.629084, 29.947421]
[-83.9019, 33.56531]
[-80.091552, 37.288422]
[-77.949231, 34.237534]
[-96.60637, 32.968131]
[-80.969088, 29.151235]
[-86.843386, 33.354666]
[-84.206, 33.462175]
[-76.342464, 36.830187]
[-79.985822, 32.898412]
[-84.2784568595722, 33.
[-88.780694, 35.674914]
[-87.898899, 30.598605]
[-83.71487, 32.614092]
[-79.523611, 36.07101]
[-91.127792, 30.580582]
[-86.352681, 35.875097]
[-90.271372, 30.023002]
[-80.205641, 25.955672]
[-81.632, 30.157]
[-86.961821, 31.454352]
[-80.666906, 35.366769]
[-97.56596, 35.406447]
[-84.364334, 35.511474]
[-81.01622, 29.23453]
[-86.57177, 34.855504]
[-84.625908, 33.399829]
[-76.344303, 36.740862]
[-84.192634, 33.517948]
[-77.83421, 39.296024]
[-77.518985, 38.359332]
[-84.45238, 38.042061]
[-83.08319, 39.840191]
[-81.993971, 33.475816]
[-95.481102, 29.913294]
[-82.699, 28.334]
[-84.352035, 33.989889]
[-86.819468, 35.945115]
[-91.009638, 30.407864]
[-81.8428, 27.9096]
```